# Converting Kendo UI Ajax Call to AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to convert this ajax to directive. The code below opens a modal window with a new route:

```
<div id="window" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;"></div>
    <span id="undo" class="k-button">Click here to open the window.</span>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var window = $("#window"),
                undo = $("#undo")
                        .bind("click", function() {

                              window.kendoWindow({
                                        actions: ["Custom", "Pin", "Refresh", "Maximize", "Minimize", "Close"],
                                        modal: true,
                                        pinned: false,
                                        resizable: false,
                                        width: "900px",
                                        height: "770px",
                                        content: "http://localhost/WebInvoice/Dev/#/client?mp=b"
                                    }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
                        });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I convert this into directive?